# Mulitchannel music creation program with samples

Tags: linux, music

I want to create songs with melodies. As I don't have a band at hand I need to synthesize the instruments (I'll record the singing).

So, I need a program that

- Has multiple channels where I can add the tracs for the various instruments (at least 8, but 16 or more would be better)
- Sample capabilities for instruments I don't have (at least piano, drum, violin, trumpet)
- Runs on my Linux machine native, offline.
- Must have a gratis trial version if its software I need to pay for.
- Must have a nice GUI.
- I'll pay for it, if need be.

Ideally it also

- Has a wave sampler (for more "techno" sounds)
- comes with a rich set of precreated, commercially usable sound samples.
- Is Open Source Software
- Is Gratis
- Has a Windows Counterpart for other members of my band that do not run linux, but I will convince them if its good.

Comment: A good friend of mine uses software from www.Steinberg.net to create studio-quality music. I am not an expert in this area, however I suggest checking out their products to see if one fits your needs.

Comment: @MrPublic I saw no linux support there. I have no use for non-linux software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at [LMMS](https://lmms.io/):

- Has multiple channels **Yep 64 of them**
- Sample capabilities for instruments I don't have (at least piano, drum, violin, trumpet) **Cello, Organs, pianos, flute, harpsichord, guitars, trumpet & violins & lots of drums.**
- Runs on my Linux machine native, offline - **Yes**
- Must have a gratis trial version if its software I need to pay for. **It is just gratis**
- Must have a nice GUI. **Some think so, others will disagree.**
- Has a wave sampler (for more "techno" sounds) **lots & lots of effects**
- comes with a rich set of precreated, commercially usable sound samples **Yes**
- Is Open Source Software **Yes**
- Is Gratis **Yes**
- Has a Windows Counterpart for other members of my band that do not run linux, but I will convince them if its good. **Linux, Windows & OS-X versions 32 & 64 bit**
- **Lots More**

[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks exactly like what I was looking for! Great! Will test it this weak.